# Appending textarea fields with line breaks using Safecracker

Tags: safecracker

Another perplexing "is probably an easy fix" question:

I have an EE site, and am using Safecracker to maintain a customer data channel. Each week, the customer receives a notice about an upcoming grocery delivery. When they do, they have the opportunity to submit a note about it – for example, "I don't want beets."

I have a another textarea field that collects all of these notes.

I was using a hidden Safecracker field to populate the textarea:

```
<input type="hidden" name="customer_bin_notes" id="customer_bin_notes" value="{customer_bin_notes}\n{customer_bin_recent_note}">
```

I can't get the line break to work. I also tried 
 and \l but those didn't work either.

I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple here.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `<br />` instead of `\n`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried <p></p> as well.

Comment: If you're placing it in an input field then I'd imagine everything will be stripped because of the type of data field it is. In the database it expecting a VARCHAR (a string) of a capped limit and EE will no doubt be parsing all input for security reasons. You'd have more flexibility submitting as a textarea rather than an input field.